# Angular authentication why save token in headers?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, authentication, client

I am new to web authentication and need some clarification.

I have seen people implementing token based authentication alongside angularjs $rootscope to save logged-in user information.

Why need to attach a token to Headers at every request if the angularjs application will only check its own variable to identify that the user logged in?

Likewise, if one has a token in every Headers, why simply check the Headers on client side to know if the user has logged in? If so, I do not see why one uses $rootscope to save logged-in user's info.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I usually save the entire user object on rootScope so as not to have to make a call on every page that is generally using the user's entire profile information. More recently, in node, I am using passport.js and doing backend authentication with angular function only on the pages its magic really helps. This is very modular as each angular app is essentially self contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you unintentionally nailed it when you said "the angularjs application will only check its own variable to identify that the user logged in".

The frontend will usually just trust that whatever kind of token it has is valid, since there is no way to do an independent verification of it (remember, there is no such thing as frontend security). The backend however can't do that, it needs to actually verify on each request that the user is who he/she claims to be, otherwise your application is not secure. Hence you send the token on each requests so that the backend can check it.

If you simply trusted the frontend to say who is logged in or not then nothing would stop an attacker from simply bypassing that check using javascript and take control of any account they wanted. Validation *always* needs to be done backend.

As for saving it in rootScope, that is mostly just a convenience thing people do for things they always want available so they don't need to get the data in all controllers. I tend to use an abstract state in ui-router or a shared factory for that instead, but it amounts to mostly the same thing.